# Android studio 2.0 Preview 8 with gradle plugin 2.0.0-alhpa8, memory warning despite heap size to 4Gb

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just updated to Android Studio version 2.0 Preview 8 and gradle plugin 2.0.0-alpha8. I noticed that now there's a warning in case the heap space is not big enough for dexing.

As they say in the proper page (http://tools.android.com/recent)

> In 2.0.0-alpha8 we've added some automatic diagnostics for this: if
>   the build process is too small, we switch back to out-of-memory dexing
>   and emit a build warning explaining how to bump up the Gradle daemon
>   size. (We're also working on some additional related improvements for
>   the next build after alpha8.)

When I went building my project I got the following error:

> To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap. It
>   currently has 3641 MB. For faster builds, increase the maximum heap
>   size for the Gradle daemon to more than 4g as specified in
>   dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize. To do this, set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g
>   as specified in dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize in the project
>   gradle.properties. For more information see
>   https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

actually, I get a lot of these in a row. Which surprises me because that's what I see in my gradle.properties file (in my project home dir)

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=16
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

also, in the build.gradle of my main module, I put

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

so I don't understand where the builder/dexer/compiler is getting that 3641MB value.

Builds are extremely slow

I Disabled instant run and now things are faster. 48-50 seconds for a build. I still get the same error but just once and not many times in a row.

I'm on Linux, my ulimit -a is the following:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31483
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31483
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Also, this is my studio.vmoptions file: https://gist.github.com/MarKco/1ae7918daf867a378a2f I guess it's unedited. I could have a custom one, but I don't know where it could be.

Comment: What OS are you on? Check your ulimit

Comment: I'm on Linux, and edited  the question to include my full ulimit.

Comment: -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m: I doubt you really need that much perm gen space.

Comment: what value would you suggest for XX:MaxPermSize ?

Comment: Update: latest builds took much less time (Total time: 10.563 secs) and are being faster and faster each time since I disabled instant run. Didn't change anything in the gradle.properties file yet

Comment: 256m or 512m perm gen space is usually enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it solved, or so it seems.
The last change I had made before I posted the question was the following:

I had

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=22
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=22
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=22
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=16
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

and I changed it to

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=16
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I don't know why it wasn't changed automatically, since I've been using 23 as target version from a long time. Anyways, after I changed from 22 to 23 I didn't have good builds yet, but that seemed to be due to a gradle sync still running in background. I killed all the gradle projects, kept the version 23 in place of 22, disabled the instant run and performed a new synchronization. At first I kept seing the "To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap." error, just one time and not repeated as it happened before. But build after build I saw build times getting lower, until I got a 10 seconds build. I guess it's solved. I hope, at least.

P.S. In the end I changed the MaxPermSize accordingly to what Henry said, now my configuration is

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=16
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```